# Failing to convert audio file from M4A to MP3 format using FFmpegWrapper

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a M4A audio file to MP3 format using `ffmpeg` in an iOS Project, language: Objective C. To make things easier I try to accomplish this using `FFmpegWrapper`

I'm using ffmpeg ver 2.8.3 and FFmpegWrapper 1.0 installed via CocoaPods. On `pod outdated` it shows that I'm using latest versions.

This is my code:

```
- (void) convertMP4ToMP3
{
    NSString *inputFormat = @"m4a";
    NSString *outputFormat = @"mp3";

    NSString *inputFileName = @"audio";
    NSString *outputFileName = @"outputAudio";

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *inputFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:inputFileName ofType:inputFormat];
    NSString *outputFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[outputFileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:outputFormat]];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];
    }

    FFmpegWrapper *wrapper = [[FFmpegWrapper alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *options = @{kFFmpegInputFormatKey : inputFormat, kFFmpegOutputFormatKey : outputFormat};
    [wrapper convertInputPath:inputFilePath outputPath:outputFilePath options:options progressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, uint64_t totalBytesRead, uint64_t totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    } completionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        success ? NSLog(@"Success!") : NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }];
}
```

**And as result conversion fails with the following logs:**

```
[mp3 @ 0x16a5ca00] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
[mp3 @ 0x16a5ca00] Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.
Error : Invalid argument
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try updating the FFmpegWrapper library.

Comment: Hi @New16. I'm using ffmpeg ver 2.8.3 and FFmpegWrapper 1.0 installed via CocoaPods. On 'pod outdated' it shows that I'm using latest versions.

Comment: You need to check with the FFmpegWrapper lib writers, it has been using deprecated methods.

Comment: Not really an answer, but AVFoundation can do this for you. Use `AVMutableComposition` and add one (mp4) track, set the output format and you're ready to go.

Comment: I didn't think `AVFoundation` offered an mp3 encoder.

Comment: I am also having above issue. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @UmairSuraj unfortunately no solution yet (